# Recognize string formatting Debug Assertion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, string-formatting, stdstring

I have a runtime problem with code below.

The purpose is to "recognize" the formats (%s %d etc) within the input string.
To do this, it returns an integer that matches the data type.
Then the extracted types are manipulated/handled in other functions.

I want to clarify that my purpose isn't to write formatted types in a string (snprintf etc.) but only to recognize/extract them.

The problem is the crash of my application with error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program:
...ers\Alex\source\repos\TestProgram\Debug\test.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\appcrt\convert\isctype.cpp
Line: 36

Expression: c >= -1 && c <= 255
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

enum Formats
{
    TYPE_INT,
    TYPE_FLOAT,
    TYPE_STRING,

    TYPE_NUM
};

typedef struct Format
{
    Formats         Type;
    char            Name[5 + 1];
} SFormat;

SFormat FormatsInfo[TYPE_NUM] =
{
    {TYPE_INT,      "d"},
    {TYPE_FLOAT,    "f"},
    {TYPE_STRING,   "s"},
};


int GetFormatType(const char* formatName)
{
    for (const auto& format : FormatsInfo)
    {
        if (strcmp(format.Name, formatName) == 0)
            return format.Type;
    }

    return -1;
}

bool isValidFormat(const char* formatName)
{
    for (const auto& format : FormatsInfo)
    {
        if (strcmp(format.Name, formatName) == 0)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool isFindFormat(const char* strBufFormat, size_t stringSize, int& typeFormat)
{
    bool foundFormat = false;
    std::string stringFormat = "";

    for (size_t pos = 0; pos < stringSize; pos++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(strBufFormat[pos]))
            continue;

        if (!isdigit(strBufFormat[pos]))
        {
            stringFormat += strBufFormat[pos];

            if (isValidFormat(stringFormat.c_str()))
            {
                typeFormat = GetFormatType(stringFormat.c_str());
                foundFormat = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return foundFormat;
}

int main()
{
    std::string testString = "some test string with %d arguments";          // crash application
    // std::string testString = "%d some test string with arguments";   // not crash application

    size_t stringSize = testString.size();

    char buf[1024 + 1];
    memcpy(buf, testString.c_str(), stringSize);
    buf[stringSize] = '\0';

    for (size_t pos = 0; pos < stringSize; pos++)
    {
        if (buf[pos] == '%')
        {
            if (buf[pos + 1] == '%')
            {
                pos++;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                char bufFormat[1024 + 1];
                memcpy(bufFormat, buf + pos, stringSize);
                bufFormat[stringSize] = '\0';

                int typeFormat;
                if (isFindFormat(bufFormat, stringSize, typeFormat))
                {
                    std::cout << "type = " << typeFormat << "\n";
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I commented in the code, with the first string everything works. While with the second, the application crashes.

I also wanted to ask you is there a better/more performing way to recognize types "%d %s etc" within a string? (even not necessarily returning an int to recognize it).

Thanks.

Comment: `memcpy(bufFormat, buf + pos, stringSize);` copies more than remaining string (`stringSize - pos` seems more appropriated)... Not sure why you copy to intermediate buffer neither, as you might directly use `std::string`, and offset (`pos`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at this `else` clause:

```
char bufFormat[1024 + 1];
memcpy(bufFormat, buf + pos, stringSize);
bufFormat[stringSize] = '\0';
```

The variable `stringSize` was initialized with the size of the original format string. Let's say it's 30 in this case.

Let's say you found the `%d` code at offset 20. You're going to copy 30 characters, starting at offset 20, into `bufFormat`. That means you're copying 20 characters past the end of the original string. You could possibly read off the end of the original `buf`, but that doesn't happen here because `buf` is large. The third line sets a NUL into the buffer at position 30, again past the end of the data, but your `memcpy` copied the NUL from `buf` into `bufFormat`, so that's where the string in `bufFormat` will end.

Now `bufFormat` contains the string "%d arguments." Inside `isFindFormat` you search for the first `isalpha` character. Possibly you meant `isalnum` here? Because we can only get to the `isdigit` line if the `isalpha` check passes, and if it's `isalpha`, it's not `isdigit`.

In any case, after `isalpha` passes, `isdigit` will definitely return `false` so we enter that `if` block. Your code will find the right type here. But, the loop doesn't terminate. Instead, it continues scanning up to `stringSize` characters, which is the `stringSize` from `main`, that is, the size of the original format string. But the string you're passing to `isFindFormat` only contains the part starting at '%'. So you're going to scan past the end of the string and read whatever's in the buffer, which will probably trigger the assertion error you're seeing.

Theres a lot more going on here. You're mixing and matching `std::string` and C strings; see if you can use `std::string::substr` instead of copying. You can use `std::string::find` to find characters in a string. If you have to use C strings, use `strcpy` instead of `memcpy` followed by the addition of a NUL.

Answer (score 0):

You could just demand it to a regexp engine which bourned to search through strings
Since C++11 there's direct support, what you have to do is

```
   #include <regex>
```

then you can match against strings using various methods, for instance **regex_match** which gives you the possibility, together with an **smatch** to find out your target with just few lines of codes using standard library

```
   std::smatch sm;
   std::regex_match ( testString.cbegin(), testString.cend(), sm, str_expr);
```

where **str_exp** is your regex to find what you want specifically
in the `sm` you have now every matched string against your regexp, which you can print in this way

```
   for (int i = 0; i < sm.size(); ++i)
   {
      std::cout << "Match:" << sm[i] << std::endl;
   }
```

**EDIT**:
to better express the result you would achieve i'll include a simple sample below

```
    // target string to be searched against
    string target_string = "simple example no.%d is: %s";
    // pattern to look for 
    regex str_exp("(%[sd])");
    // match object
    smatch sm;
    // iteratively search your pattern on the string, excluding parts of the string already matched 
    cout << "My format strings extracted:" << endl;
    while (regex_search(target_string, sm, str_exp))
    {
        std::cout << sm[0] << std::endl;
        target_string = sm.suffix();
    }
```

you can easily add any format string you want modifying the **str_exp** regex expression.